# Socket sends duplicate messages to client

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I am setting up a web socket server with socket.io and it seems like that messages are sent at least twice. Sometimes even trice. (very rarely even 4+ times) They are never sent once though.  How should I setup my handlers or my client code so every message is received exactly once all the time?

My client is in swift and my server in node.js. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on the server itself.

*Node.js:*

```
// Here is an array of all connections to the server
var connections = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {

  socket.on('add-user', function(user) {

    connections[user.id] = {
      "socket": socket.id
    };

  });

  socket.on('chat-message', function(message) {

    console.log(message);

    if (connections[message.receiver]) {

      console.log("Send to: " + connections[message.receiver].socket);

// Here are some varients of the emit command. Seems like they all do the same      

//io.sockets.connected[connections[message.receiver].socket].emit("chat-message", message);
      //io.to(connections[message.receiver].socket).emit("chat-message", message);

      socket.broadcast.to(connections[message.receiver].socket).emit("chat-message", message);

    } else {
      console.log("Send push notification")

    }
  });

  //Removing the socket on disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("The client disconnected");
    for (var id in connections) {
      if (connections[id].socket === socket.id) {
        delete connections[id];
      }
    }
  })
}
```

The "console.log(message);" in the messages handler is only called once. That's the confusing part for me. If the handler is called twice, why is this only printed once? Still, on the handler in my swift code, the handler for received messages is called multiple times.

Comment: Is the loop-back necessary? is there a reason the client should receive their own message back (instead of just an ACK)? Is the client printing the message they sent as well as the message they received?

Comment: I am not familiar with the fact that the sender also gets the message back. At least practically speaking it doesn't happen. The client is sending a message but not getting it back. That is by purpose like that. Did I write something that would cause the behaviour you described?

Comment: My bad, I was only skimming the `broadcast` code, not reading it properly.

Comment: No problem at all. Any idea what I could change to address my previously mentioned problem?

Comment: nope... I’m not sure there’s enough information for an answer.

Comment: Why did you using `socket.broadcast.to` if you want emit message to one socket? May be problem in this? In socket.io by default each socket is in two rooms: `/` (root) and in `<socket.id>`. And for what list of sockets in variable `connections`? Socket.IO provide list of connected sockets.

Comment: I used `io.sockets`,`io.to` and `socket.broadcast.to`. I haven't noticed any difference. I have my `connections` array to be able to identify every client by their `user.id` from the database. I didn't know though that every client is in two rooms by default. How can I only use one room but still emit my message to just one client? (I assume that we both think that the message is emitted to both rooms. That would make two messages received for the client. But what about these rare cases when I receive the message 3+ times?)

Comment: I had a similar problem when run two socket.io backends with socket.io-redis. Are you have use `https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis`?